# Rails: What is the location option for in the render method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Hey I am wondering what the location option for the render method in rails is. The docs here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html states:

"You can use the :location option to set the HTTP Location header:"

But I have no idea why you would do this, or what you would use this for.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually `location` option is used to redirect to a new resource as part of processing the request. For example,

```
 render :xml => post.to_xml, :status => :created, :location => post_url(post)
```

is telling the recipient that a XML file for the post is created and you will get this from `post_url(post)`. Hence GO THERE ;)

`render` method does this by setting the `Location` option in response object

```
... ... ... 
if location = options[:location]
    response.headers["Location"] = url_for(location)
end
... ... ...
```

You can find details about `Location` header here    http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30.

Comment: oh ok. so for example if the client did a ajax call to the server, and then in the response, location was defined to some url, then the ajax is supposed to (according to the response) go the url specified by the location. Otherwise if there is no location, then done

Comment: Yes... Exactly!!
Though I didnt try with an Ajax call but should work like that!!

Comment: What about during an ajax request? Why would you want to set the location header? Wouldn't it redirect from the ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

The `Location header` is for redirecting the page.