# Rails authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I'm trying to redirect to the root_path if authentication fails.
Currently, it's just changing the body of the page with HTTP Basic: Access denied.

Here is my controller:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
 before_filter :http_basic_auth, only: [:show]

  def http_basic_auth
    if (authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user, password| password == @project.passcode && user == @project.passcode end if @project.private?)
    true
    else
      response.headers["Location"] = url_for(root_path)
    end
  end

end
```

Researched the following but I'm still not able to get it right:
[Rails: What is the location option for in the render method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084431/rails-what-is-the-location-option-for-in-the-render-method)

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/ControllerMethods.html#method-i-authenticate_with_http_basic

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-and-response-objects

Comment: why don't you use `redirect_to root_path`?

Comment: I tried it but didn't work

Comment: it surely works. it may be something wrong with your condition not with `redirect_to`

Comment: definitely, I'll keep trying

Answer (score 2):

I you still haven't gotten this to work:

Try use `authenticate_with_http_basic` in place of `authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic`

An snippet of an example from the [Rails API documentation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb#L36):

```
    if user = authenticate_with_http_basic { |u, p| @account.users.authenticate(u, p) }
      @current_user = user
    else
      request_http_basic_authentication
    end
```

Comment: both options work but still haven't been able to redirect to root path if the user closes or cancels the pop-up window.